# CSS width of absolute positioned drop down menu and IE7 issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, width, css-position

how can I automatically define width of drop down menu depending on the contained links length:

Here are pictures of what I have and what I want:

This is reality:

[image]

This is what I need to get:

[image]

Here is my html and css (I reduced the HTML as much as possible - just left the menu):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

        <style type="text/css">
/* Main styles */

/*drop default browser css settings*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-weight: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
outline: 0;
}
body {
font: .8em 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet,Verdana, sans-serif;
line-height: 1;
color: #444;
background: white;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;

}
caption, th, td {
text-align: left;
font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: "" "";
}

#second_menu {
    margin: 25px 25px 0 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #BBBBBB;
}

#second_menu li {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    padding: 10px 20px 15px 0;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

#second_menu li a {
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#second_menu li.multiple > a {
    cursor: default;
}

#second_menu li:hover a,
#second_menu li.current a {
    color: #6F8936;
}

#second_menu li.multiple a span {
    background: url(../img/icons/sprite10.png) no-repeat -244px -370px;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#second_menu li.multiple:hover a span,
#second_menu li.multiple.current a span {
    background-position: -244px -379px;
}

#second_menu ul.subnav {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 39px;
    left: -10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px dotted #BBBBBB;
    border-top: none;
}

#second_menu .subnav li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#second_menu .subnav li a {
    color: #868686;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#second_menu .subnav li a:hover {
    color: #616161;
    background-color: #DFEBBD;
}

#second_menu li.multiple .subnav {
    display: none;
}

#second_menu li.multiple:hover .subnav {
    display: block;
}

    </style>
    </head>

<body id="main-page">

<div id="user-message-container"></div>
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div id="user-block">

        </div>
       <div id="header-wrapper">
           <div id="header-left">
           <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://mysite.com/" title=""></a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="header-menu">
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="header-content">
        <div id="info-search">
        </div>
        <ul id="second_menu">
                    <li class="current multiple"><a href="#">MENU1<span></span></a>
                        <ul class="subnav">
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">Short name</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">This is a very long name</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">Shorty</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li class="multiple"><a href="#">MENU2<span></span></a>
                        <ul class="subnav">
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">submenu1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">submenu2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">MENU3</a>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">MENU4</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="multiple"><a href="#">MENU5<span></span></a>
                        <ul class="subnav">
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">submenu1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">submenu2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">MENU6</a>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/">MENU7</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Header -->
<div class="clear"></div>



<!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">


<!-- // Main content (left column) -->
    <!-- Sidebar (right column) -->
    <div id="sidebar">

    </div>
    <!-- // Sidebar (right column) -->
<div class="clear"></div> </div>
<!-- // Wrapper -->



<!-- Footer -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">

</div>

<!-- // Footer  -->

</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate any help with this.

PS another issue is in IE7 - when I move cursor from menu name to submenu block - the submenu block dissapears as if :hover effect is lost.

Comment: I put it in a jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/EUj69/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `white-space: nowrap` to your subnav links - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUj69/6/)

```css
#second_menu .subnav li a {
    color: #868686;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: nowrap; /* this */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. That seems to solve the issue with width of the submenu links. Do you have any idea how to fix the IE7 issue, when you move cursor from menu name to submenu block - it disappears as if :hover is lost?

Comment: @Volder can't reproduce the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/dGV2V/1/ can you edit the fiddle to replicate it?

Comment: fiddle doesn't support browser compatibility, at least I didn't find any - I was using IETester for this purpose (to check in IE7), anyway I just added special css for IE7 and the dropdownmenu is simply higher and the hover is not lost.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: relative` from `#second_menu li`
Remove `top: 39px;` and  `left: -10px;` from `#second_menu ul.subnav`
Add `margin-left:-10px` to `#second_menu ul.subnav`
Add `display:block;` to `#second_menu li a`

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/EUj69/10

Edit: IE7 fix

Comment: Than you for proposal, but when you remove position:relative from #second_menu li - in IE7 the submenu starts be displayed in the top left corner of the page - this is basically why I added this. Also I found that for ABSOLUTE positioning of element you need a parent element with position other than static + you need to use top and left parameters instead of margin.

Comment: It was  margin-left, not margin, sorry about that. And I added an IE fix

Comment: thanks for that, using your solution - I'm still struggling with 2 issues in IE7: the level of multiple menu and single ones (no drop down) are different - multiple are a bit higher (this happens when I add display: block to #second_menu li a). The other issue is that when you hover on submenu links - the green background covers only text, but not the whole width of submenu. Trying to play with width - but no result. Both are only in IE7 issues.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that. But I don't think a lot of people will notice this, because only 1.8% of the world uses IE7 nowadays.  

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, basically your solution works out also good, but as the second with nowrap was much simpler - I used it instead. Unfortunately, I can't mark both as a solution.